# Is there anyway to open default browser inside webview like gmail does?

Tags: java, android, webview

I am looking for a way to open all my links in the default browser but within the webview like Gmail does. You may look into the Gmail application and how it opens all the links within using the mobile default browser. I think somebody has tried it.

My codes MainActivity.Java

```
package com.example.google;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;
    ProgressBar pgBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        pgBar = findViewById(R.id.pgBar);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

        webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()   {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    if((String.valueOf(request.getUrl())).contains("https://www.yahoo.com/")) {
                        view.loadUrl(String.valueOf(request.getUrl()));
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, request.getUrl());
                        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }


        });
    }
}
```

You may click here to check the screenshots

[image]
[image]